# Unable to access user Twitter email address using Fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am getting the following error even after the user allows email access

```
"Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address"
```

Although twitter support is saying that

```
"Your app has all necessary permissions to request user emails. "
```

and on apps.twitter.com in permissions it is said that

```
Can request a user's email address
```

my code is

```
 TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
            authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<String> result) {
                    // Do something with the result, which provides the email address

                    Log.i("email","Access granted");
                    Toast.makeText(LinkedInActivity.this,"Access granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    // Do something on failure

                    Log.i("email","Access denied"+exception.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(LinkedInActivity.this,"Access denied"+exception.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue ..the issue is that the Twitter was already logon ..Although I have sign out several times but didn't worked .

Then i clear the cache and data of twitter app then run my app and now I am able to access the email address from twitter using fabric